# Labels in Bar Chart vanish when scrolled up in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, dashboard

I have created a bar chart in a WinForms C# application. The chart includes a scrollbar to navigate through a number of data points on the X-axis. However, I'm encountering an issue where the X-axis labels disappear when I scroll up, making it difficult to interpret the chart. However when scrolled down, it shows fine. It just vanishes when it I scroll it up.

Screenshot when scrolled up: https://prnt.sc/ZKxLy_TB010E

Screenshot when scrlled down: https://prnt.sc/MOcn3D5FrfQc

```cs
//          // 
            // This is my chartBarangay in the Designer code.
            // 
            this.chartBarangay.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderlineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderlineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderlineWidth = 0;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderSkin.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderSkin.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderSkin.BorderDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Solid;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderSkin.BorderWidth = 0;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderSkin.PageColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.chartBarangay.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
            chartArea5.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
            chartArea5.AxisX.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 8;
            chartArea5.AxisX.LabelAutoFitMinFontSize = 5;
            chartArea5.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Montserrat Medium", 9.749999F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            chartArea5.AxisX.LabelStyle.TruncatedLabels = true;
            chartArea5.AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            chartArea5.AxisX.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
            chartArea5.AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
            chartArea5.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            chartArea5.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            chartArea5.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
            chartArea5.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Size = 3F;
            chartArea5.AxisX.MaximumAutoSize = 50F;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScaleView.MinSize = 0D;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 4D;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 1D;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScrollBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScrollBar.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            chartArea5.AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 15D;
            chartArea5.AxisX.TitleForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            chartArea5.AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
            chartArea5.AxisY.IsMarginVisible = false;
            chartArea5.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            chartArea5.AxisY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            chartArea5.AxisY.LineWidth = 0;
            chartArea5.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            chartArea5.AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            chartArea5.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Size = 3F;
            chartArea5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            chartArea5.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            chartArea5.BorderWidth = 0;
            chartArea5.IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes = true;
            chartArea5.Name = "ChartArea1";
            chartArea5.ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            this.chartBarangay.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea5);
            legend5.Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Far;
            legend5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
            legend5.BorderDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
            legend5.Docking = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Top;
            legend5.Enabled = false;
            legend5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Montserrat", 9.749999F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            legend5.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            legend5.IsTextAutoFit = false;
            legend5.LegendStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LegendStyle.Row;
            legend5.Name = "Legend1";
            legend5.TitleFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Montserrat Medium", 8.249999F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            legend5.TitleForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            legend5.TitleSeparatorColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            this.chartBarangay.Legends.Add(legend5);
            this.chartBarangay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(491, 76);
            this.chartBarangay.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.chartBarangay.Name = "chartBarangay";
            this.chartBarangay.Palette = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.None;
            series5.BorderDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
            series5.BorderWidth = 5;
            series5.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series5.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
            series5.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(155)))), ((int)(((byte)(80)))));
            series5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Montserrat", 9.749999F);
            series5.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            series5.Legend = "Legend1";
            series5.MarkerBorderWidth = 0;
            series5.MarkerColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            series5.MarkerSize = 10;
            series5.Name = "Illness";
            series5.ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            series5.SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;
            series5.SmartLabelStyle.CalloutBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            series5.SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineAnchorCapStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
            series5.SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
            series5.SmartLabelStyle.CalloutStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LabelCalloutStyle.None;
            series5.SmartLabelStyle.IsOverlappedHidden = false;
            this.chartBarangay.Series.Add(series5);
            this.chartBarangay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(460, 200);
            this.chartBarangay.TabIndex = 21;
            this.chartBarangay.Text = "chart1";
            title5.Alignment = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
            title5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Montserrat", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            title5.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(198)))), ((int)(((byte)(61)))), ((int)(((byte)(47)))));
            title5.Name = "Title1";
            title5.Text = "Deaths by Barangay";
            this.chartBarangay.Titles.Add(title5);
```